# Input Checkboxes not being checked off on page load; but being checked of after using "alert()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a table with a list of 5 items that is dynamically generated using AJAX with a PHP/MySQL backend. Each item has an INPUT Checkbox next to it.

Upon page load, some of the checkboxes must appear "checked" depending on a set of values returned by PHP/MySQL. Thus:

```
var checked_items = [];
// var checked_items = new Array(); // this is not working either
var GetItemsFromXML;
var SplitItems;
var XMLItemsObj = new Object;

// function...
function DisplayItems() {

 CreateRObj(function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

  GetItemsFromXML=xmlhttp.responseText; // returns pike delim list

  SplitItems = GetItemsFromXML.split("|"); // split at pike

  // status - either "all" or "selected"
   XMLItemsObj.checkedstatus = SplitItems[0];

  // drop last ","
  SplitItems[1] = SplitItems[1].substr(0,SplitItems[1].lastIndexOf(","));

  // split at comma and pass to variable
  checked_items = SplitItems[1].split(","); 

   }
 });

 xmlhttp.open("POST","loaditems.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

At this point, the variable "checked_items", contains the values returned by PHP/MySQL.
These values will determine which checkbox is checked off.

I've confirmed that this variable is populated by testing to see if it is empty (""), 
undefined, or null.

Now, Once the page loads, the code below loops through all the checkboxes and checks them off depending on the "XMLItemsObj.checkedstatus" status. If status is "selected", then only some are checked off. If status is "all", all checkboxes are supposed to be checked off.

Here's the code that does this:

```
if (XMLItemsObj.checkedstatus=="selected") {
  for (i=0; i < checked_items.length; i++) {
   $(":checkbox[value="+checked_items[i]+"]").attr("checked",true);
  }

} else if (XMLItemsObj.checkedstatus=="all") {

  $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
   $("input:checkbox").attr("checked",true);
  });
}
```

Here's where things start getting weird...

The above only seems to work when I use the "alert" function 
to check for the values in the "checked_items" variable. It works 
when ".checkedstatus" is "all" or when its "selected".

Thus, if I were to use, for example this code:

```
alert("The values of the checked_items variable are: "+checked_items);
```

Then, the above code will work perfectly.

However, it doesn't work otherwise. Neither when status is "all", nor 
when status is "selected".

I'm at a loss, but my guess it that the variable is either losing its 
value, or the event(s) are not being triggered. However, I'm not sure.

Anyone has any ideas? All comments, insights, solutions, and thoughts 
are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first guess would be that this code is running before the DOM is ready. Is your JS enclosed in a `$(document).ready()` call?

Comment: Also, there's no need for a `.each()` loop in that second code snippet. `$('input:checkbox').attr` will be applied to every item in the set, so it's not necessary to perform that multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is catch  `Upon page load, some of the checkboxes must appear "checked"` Ensure your script runs when DOM structure of target is created. Then it must work.

Comment: @Hans Engel - Thanks. I didn't even consider that. I was thinking that the "xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200" AJAX part took care of all the DOM/page loading. Am I wrong on this? Also, all my code is within the "DisplayItems()" function; this includes any AJAX calls. Would it make sense to put the "$(document).ready()" call right after start of function; or after the AJAX calls? And thanks for the tip about dropping the "each()" call.

Comment: @Hans Engel - Added the "$(document).ready()" but no luck. Checkboxes are only checked off either on page reload or when using "alert()" function. Any other ideas? Is there another way to check that DOM has been created or loaded?